# receive XML and insert to Postgres DB using Nifi

Tags: xml, postgresql, apache-nifi

I'm trying to create a Nifi flow which performs the below logic:

1- Receive HTTP XML request from External system and send ok response.

2- Process the XML data and extract specific fields form the XML body.

3- Insert the extracted fields to a postgres DB table.

below is a sample of the XML body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>XMLRecord</methodName>
<params>
<param>
<value>
<struct>
<member>
<name>MainID</name>
<value>
<string>123456789</string>
</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>origintimestapmp</name>
<value>
<dateTime.iso8601>20211129T14:10:11+0200</dateTime.iso8601>
</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>Xvalue</name>
<value>
<string>5.000000</string>
</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>DataFields</name>
<value>
<struct>
<member>
<name>Action1</name>
<value>
<string />
</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>Acttion2</name>
<value>
<string />
</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>Action3</name>
<value>
<string>Mirror</string>
</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>Action4</name>
<value>
<string>Reactivated</string>
</value>
</member>
</struct>
</value>
</member>
</struct>
</value>
</param>
</params>
</methodCall>
```

the data to be extracted in this format:

MainID,origintimestamp,Xvalue,Action1,Action2,Action3,Action4

sample output:

123456789,20211129T14:10:11+0200,5.000000,,,Mirror,Reactivated

and then inserted to the Database table with the same structure.

I've managed to achieve the part related to receiving the request and sending the response and connecting to the postgres DB. but I couldn't manage to parse the XML and convert it to database insert format.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance,

Comment: you need PutDatabaseRecord with xmlreader. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.15.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord/

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to parse any XML document and put the data into a Postgres table in NiFi. One way is to use PutDatabaseRecord with an [XMLReader](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.7.0/org.apache.nifi.xml.XMLReader/index.html) controller service.

Alternatively, a simple but elaborative approach for understanding NiFi better could be the below one.

NiFi Flow: [EvaluateXPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateXPath/) -> [AttributesToJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AttributesToJSON/) -> [PutDatabaseRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord/)

1. `EvaluateXPath` processor will extract the required data in the
   Flowfile attributes (destination) using XPaths evaluations. [SplitXml](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitXml/index.html) can be used for multiple instances of parent elements.
   You can add a property for each attribute as below.

   mainid - `//member[name='MainID']/value/string/text()`

   origintimestapmp - `//member[name='origintimestapmp']/value/dateTime.iso8601`

   action1 - `//member[name='Action1']/value/string/text()`
   and so on...
2. `AttributesToJSON` generates JSON representation of the input FlowFile
   attributes which are nothing but the data points in our case.

   Attributes List - `mainid,origintimestamp,xvalue,action1,action2,action3,action4`

   Destination - `flowfile-content`

   Include Core Attributes - `false`
3. `PutDatabaseRecord` reads the input JSON FlowFile using JsonTreeReader controller service and loads the data
   into the table with configured DBCPConnectionPool. Alternatively, we can use a combination of
   [ConvertJSONToSQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertJSONToSQL/index.html) and [PutSQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL/).